# When defining an Association with Rails do you require to index the foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So when I define an association in rails do I have to set the foreign key as an index in the database?

My friend told me to do this to improve performance, but he is a PHP programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your friend is correct it will help the database get the answer for your query faster

Comment: Awesome! High five! Just what I needed to know.